# VBA can't send calendar appointment

Tags: vba, calendar, appointment

When I manually make a calendar reminder/appointment, I can then click "Invite Attendees" and chose the people to invite and then click "Send" and everyone will receive that calendar reminder/appointment.

I have the following code to make a reminder programmatically, but it won't send to the intended recipients. If I open the reminder after the script has run and click on "Invite Attendees" I can see the list is filled with the people I want to send the reminder to, so I'm not really sure why it's not actually sending the reminder to them.

Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

```
Private Function CreateAppointment(SubjectStr As String, BodyStr As String, StartTime As Date, EndTime As Date, AllDay As Boolean)
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim Appt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    ' Only create the reminder if there's no duplicate
    If (CheckForDuplicates(SubjectStr) = False) Then
        Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set Appt = olApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
        Appt.Recipients.Add ("John Doe")
        Appt.Recipients.ResolveAll
        Appt.Subject = SubjectStr
        Appt.Start = StartTime
        Appt.End = EndTime
        Appt.AllDayEvent = AllDay
        Appt.Body = BodyStr
        Appt.ReminderSet = True
        Appt.Save
        Appt.Send
    End If
    Set Appt = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Hm, yeah, I see what you mean! Just tried it. I don't know why it doesn't get sent! +1 useful question.

Comment: Same here.  I saw a property called "SendUsingAccount" where you can set like this:  _Application.Session.Accounts(1)_ .  You'd do this before you saved the item.  It still had no effect.  I changed accounts (e.g. tried it on my pop3 instead of company Exchange server).  Also, I loaded up a Virtual Instance of Windows 2000 and Outlook XP and tried it there.  No luck and no response why it didn't work. :P  The funny thing is on Windows 2000 I was getting a security popup on the send line saying "This app is about to try to send something.  Do you want to allow?"  I say allow but nothing.

Comment: That's better than I've managed to get even. Macro security denotes any send function must notify user before sending, so you must have done something semi-right...
Hopefully someone will come across this and have an answer for us.

Comment: The code works fine, tested in Outlook 2010. I removed the `If (CheckForDuplicates(SubjectStr) = False) Then` If statement because that was not listed. Note that due to security, some things can **only** be done in VBA via putting your code in "VbaProject.OTM". If you put it elsewhere, it will fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A meeting is a specific type of appointment -- an appointment that other people are invited to.

In order to make an appointment a meeting, you need to do more than just invite attendees. You need to set the status to 'Meeting'. Add this to your code:

```
Appt.MeetingStatus = olMeeting
```

Also note that you set a reminder, but didn't set a reminder time. For example,

```
Appt.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 30
```

Finally, if this is Outlook VBA, why are you using CreateObject? You should be using the native Application Object to derive all your objects.

i.e. instead of

```
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

you would use

```
Set olApp = Outlook.Application
```

HTH

Comment: Much appreciated JP! Didn't realise I needed to set it to a meeting type.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, didn't get it to work until I replaced

```
Appt.Recipients.Add ("John Doe")
Appt.Recipients.ResolveAll
```

With

```
Appt.RequiredAttendees = "john.doe@email.com"
```

Regards

Chris